# Saving Player's Position is not working in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity, it is almost completed but I am having a issue with saving and loading player's position. I am using custom binary files method. Whenever I hit save button, and then load the game, it shows the saving position for a second and then again show me on my loading position. I want my player to remain on the saving position. 
I used the Brackeys tutorial to do this.

```cs
public void SaveGame()
{
    PlayerPositionData save = new PlayerPositionData();
    save.position[0] = transform.position.x;
    save.position[1] = transform.position.y;
    save.position[2] = transform.position.z;
    SavingSystem<PlayerPositionData>
        .Save(Application.persistentDataPath + "/file10.pqr", save);

}

public void LoadGame()
{
    PlayerPositionData data = SavingSystem<PlayerPositionData>
        .Load(Application.persistentDataPath + "/file10.pqr");
    Vector3 position;
    position.x = data.position[0];
    position.y = data.position[1];
    position.z = data.position[2];
    transform.position = position;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerPositionData
{
    public float[] position;

    public PlayerPositionData()
    {
        position = new float[3];
    }
}
```

The saving and loading functions are in PlayerPosition class which is a component of my player. I am not getting any error in console. not a single one. Also, at various points, I print my position using debug.log, so I am sure that my position is correctly saving, loading, and assigning into the player's position.  But after a second, it returns me to the position at which I load the game. Other things correctly saving and loading like number of bullets, health etc but there is a problem in player's position.

Also, I made a seperate loading and saving functions where binary formatters and stream work is going on. Can anyone help me? I am a student and I have to submit this project in this week. I am working on this 
position problem since one week but I got no clue how to fix this.

Comment: And this code runs on your player? Just to check..

Comment: Yes it runs ...

Comment: Does your player have some code in its start function that is resetting its position?

Comment: Firstly, No. Secondly, even if I hit load button after saving and not quitting game (because in this case, start function not called), it still gives the same error. And after quitting, and then hitting load button also gives the same error.

Comment: I didnt ask if it runs @KhubaibAlam, i asked if it runs on your player, if not it is remembering the position of the object its on and would explain the behaviour

Comment: @BugFinder, yes it runs on my player, the script is attached to the player.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question. You should have checked the tick on "Auto Sync Transform" which is on  Edit >> Project Settings >> Physics. It will allows you to set the position of a gameobject through coding.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue, resolved it by following the instructions by @khubiab. Much appreciated.

Comment: As it's currently written, your answer does not add anything to the topic. Please, look up [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)